# LINQ to Entity: How to include a conditional where condition

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm new to EntityFramework and came across a problem with an unsupported function used in the Query.
Therefore I hope the community might help to find a elegant way.
**The query tries to find a user based on the username and/or the windows username.**

```cs
[Flags]
public enum IdentifierType
{
    Username = 1,
    Windows = 2,
    Any = Username | Windows,
}
```

The following code throws an **NotSupportedException** because the Enum.HasFlag is cannot be translated into a store expression.

```cs
public User GetUser(IdentifierType type, string identifier, bool loadRelations = false)
{
    using (var context = contextFactory.Invoke())
    {
        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == identifier && type.HasFlag(IdentifierType.Username)
        || u.WindowsUsername == identifier && type.HasFlag(IdentifierType.Windows));

        return user;
    }
}
```

If I rewrite the query the old Fashion way, the Query works but the boolean logic is executed in the DB:

```cs
public User GetUser(IdentifierType type, string identifier, bool loadRelations = false)
{
    using (var context = contextFactory.Invoke())
    {
        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == identifier && (type & IdentifierType.Username) == IdentifierType.Username
        || u.WindowsUsername == identifier && (type & IdentifierType.Windows) == IdentifierType.Windows);

        return user;
    }
}
```

> WHERE ((Username = @username) AND (1 = (3 & (1)))) OR (WindowsUsername
>   = @windowsusername) AND (2 = (3 & (2))))

**How can I force the framework to evaluate the boolean logic before it is sent to the DB, so the binary operation is not done at DB Level?**

Any ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I've realized that the question did not point out the effective problem. After reading more about that, I had to rewrite the question and finally got a great answer from Gert Arnold, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621450/dynamic-where-clause-or-in-linq-to-entities).

The [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) provides powerful extensions like the **PredicateBuilder** to cover dynamic queries with OR conditions.

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
public User GetUser(IdentifierType type, string identifier, bool loadRelations = false)
{
    using (var context = contextFactory.Invoke())
    {
        IdentifierType tw = type & IdentifierType.Windows;
        IdentifierType tu = type & IdentifierType.Username;
        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == identifier && tu == IdentifierType.Username
        || u.WindowsUsername == identifier && tw == IdentifierType.Windows);

        return user;
    }
}
```

But I hope and believe that the database server detect that 1 = (3 & (1)) is a constant

Comment: Hi. This still does the binary Operation on the DB. I thought there must be a way so the Entity Framework **does only send the WHERE conditions to the DB which are enabled by the flag**. E.g. if (1 & 2) == 1 then it does not add the WHERE Username=@identifier condition to the query.

Comment: @ThomasZweifel in my sample you will have 1 = 1 instead of (1 & 2) = 1. I do not think that what you ask is implemented. The only way I imagine is a 'switch like' coding with the 3+1 cases. But I think the db server will do the optimisation, as .net would at excecution time.

Comment: @ThomasZweifel try by inverting the && clauses: instead of a && b || c && d, try b && a || d && c to see if .net [optimisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) is 'used'.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (I've converted my code to yours so may not be syntactically 100%) ...

```
public User GetUser(IdentifierType type, string identifier, bool loadRelations = false)
{
    using (var context = contextFactory.Invoke())
    {
        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == ((type.HasFlag(IdentifierType.Username)) ? identifier : u.Username) && 
    && u.WindowsUsername == ((type.HasFlag(IdentifierType.Username)) ? identifier : u.WindowsUsername);

        return user;
    }
}
```